# Migration to Elasticsearch 6 : request with script and params not working anymore

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6.8

I am migrating my Elasticsearch from v5.16 to 6.8 (and after to 7.16) but I have some problem with this type of request (see below) : using params['_source'] in a script
I don't understand why. I didn't find any breakings changes in the documentation. Can you please help me ?
FYI : the index mapping doesn't not contain "evts"

Thanks

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "closed": "false" }
        },
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "source": "(params['_source']['evts'] !== null) && (params['_source']['evts']).length > 0",
              "lang": "painless"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }}
```

The response

```
{
  "took": 6,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 2,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 3,
    "failures": [
      {
        "shard": 1,
        "index": "myIndex",
        "node": "XXX",
        "reason": {
          "type": "script_exception",
          "reason": "runtime error",
          "script_stack": [
            "(params['_source']['evts'] !== null) && (params['_source']['evts']).length > 0",
            "       ^---- HERE"
          ],
          "script": "(params['_source']['evts'] !== null) && (params['_source']['piecesJointes']).length > 0",
          "lang": "painless",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "null_pointer_exception",
            "reason": "Cannot invoke \"Object.getClass()\" because \"callArgs[0]\" is null"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it relates to this post https://discuss.elastic.co/t/painless-access-params-source-in-script-filter-in-6-1/115449, so the answer seems to be that your just can't access _source in a filter context with painless (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-filter-context.html)

Comment: Ah.. thanks @PierreMallet
Thats works in version 5.6 but not in v6 :'( ... So how can i made the request ?

Comment: You need to update your mapping to index 'evts', then do an updateByQuery (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) to reindex all your documents, then use an exists query (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) instead of your script. And bonus : it will perform way better ! ;D

Comment: Ok thank you, that what i tried yesterday afternoon but the query with exists doesn't return what I want.... 

With must_not exist : return all (even if evts.size > 0)
`{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "evts"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`


With must_not exist : return no data

`{
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "evts"
    }
  }
}
`

Comment: But, this query works (and with must_not) : 

`{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "evts",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": {
                  "exists": {
                    "field": "evts"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

summary from the comments :

As explain [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/painless-access-params-source-in-script-filter-in-6-1/115449) since since version 6.X its no longer possible to access the source in query to filter documents. Only doc_values are accessible ( [see here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-filter-context.html) ).

The clean way to execute such query without script is to add `evts` to the mapping and use an `exists` query combined with a `must_not` clause.

In this case since `evts` is a nested field a working query can be

```
{
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "evts",
                "query": {
                  "exists": {
                    "field": "evts"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```